# Spring JDBC ResultSetMetaData "getColumnName()" method returns an empty string

Tags: java, spring, jdbc, resultset

I have the following section of code to implement a drop-down menu. Based on the two parameters selected from the menu, I run the corresponding query by replacing the selected column with the mapped column name.

```
String sql = "SELECT ?, ? FROM <table_name>";

ArrayList<Some_POJO> res = this.jdbcTemplate.query(sql, new ResultSetExtractor<Some_POJO>()
    {//logic goes here.},
    user_inputs_as_object_array);
```

Now, in the logic section, I'm using the following command to map the returned values:

```
while(rs.next()) {
    Some_POJO = new SOME_POJO();
    Some_POJO.setParam1(rs.getString("SOME_COLUMN_NAME")); //ERROR
}
```

Now, the marked line fails when I refer to column by name. But what is surprising is, the following workaround works:

```
while(rs.next()) {
    Some_POJO = new SOME_POJO();
    int i = 1;
    Some_POJO.setParam1(rs.getString(i)); //Works(?!)
}
```

I tried to modify the JDBC template call to return the ResultSetMetaData object instead of an ArrayList of Some_POJO:

```
String sql = "SELECT ?, ? FROM <table_name>";

ResultSetMetaData res = this.jdbcTemplate.query(sql, new ResultSetExtractor<ResultSetMetaData>()
    {//extractData now returns rs.getMetaData()},
    user_inputs_as_object_array);

try
    {
        System.out.println("Column cout: " + res.getColumnCount());
        for(int i = 1; i <= res.getColumnCount(); i++)
            System.out.println("Label: " + res.getColumnLabel(i) +  "\nName: " + res.getColumnName(i));
    }
    catch(SQLException sqle)
```

Only to get:

```
Column cout: 2
Label: :1
Name: 
Label: :2
Name:
```

Could someone please shed some light into what is happening and (except for suggestions suggesting a complete redesign) what would be the most optimal way to achieve the expected functionality? I would prefer not to use column indexes since order changes would break the functionality.

Comment: A database might or might not return a name, depends on the JDBC driver. However you haven't told which database or jdbc driver you are using.

Comment: @M.Deinum We are using the SAP HANA Database, the JDBC driver for the same. However, I don't think that this is an issue of the driver. In a few other places, where we have not set the columns as "?"/placeholders, we are able to refer to the columns by column name. I suspect that this is some quirk of how Spring JDBC works internally.

Comment: EHrm... You are only allowed to use `?` in the where clause... Not anywhere else... This has nothing to do with spring but how jdbc works.

Comment: Also if you only have 2 columns, and you don't know the name how can you hardcode them in your extractor?!

Comment: @M.Deinum That depends on the database, some database allow use of `?` in the select, some require explicit casting of the parameter for type information, some will disallow it entirely.

Comment: You will need to use `? as some_column_name` to get it to work.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Interesting. that some drivers support it, I always thought it was disallowed (or if it worked it was shear luck). The issue is that the ? gets replaced after the meta data is build (afaik) something with binding the parameters. Which is probably why `as column_name` makes it work as now there is an alias.

Comment: @M.Deinum Some databases will default to - for example - varchar, others require explicit casting (eg `select (? as timestamp) ...` , and some drivers/databases allow dynamic typing where the data type is unknown until execution time when the driver specifies the data type (inferred from the value set).

Comment: what has providing as alias to do with the SQL type?! I don't see that connection... (But that deviates from the question asked by the original poster). He was referring to names...

Comment: @M.Deinum I thought you were saying that use of `?` in the select clause was never allowed.

Comment: I indeed did... But I didn't see the correlation between `?` and you mentioning the type. My experience is that using `?` anywhere else then the `where` clause leads to issues with JDBC. (Like not getting column names, or failing totally).

Comment: In any case, the values being returned from the database are correct. So, whether the API allows it or not seems to be a little irrelevant (IMHO). It's just that I can't refer to the data by the column name at the Java layer. I have to refer to it by an index.

Comment: @M.Deinum For most database it is a problem because they can't infer the type of the parameter (hence the casting). The JDBC specification doesn't really care about the location of parameters, as long as drivers support all features supported by the underlying database, and support the minimum feature set of SQL-92.

Comment: You can refer it by column label **if you add an `as`-clause**.

Comment: For most databases, `?` can only substitute a value (and so is legal anywhere a value may go, possibly with some language constraints) but never an identifier.

Answer (score 0):

Just for refactoring code, get values as:

```
    ArrayList result = new ArrayList(0);
    result.addAll(this.jdbcTemplate.query(sql, (RowMapper) (rs, rowNum) -> {
        POJO out = new POJO();
        out.setProperty1(rs.getString("prop1"));
        out.setProperty2(rs.getString("prop2"));
        ...
        return out;
    }));
```

For me it works fine, passing field name in method, don't think that there are some troubles with spring jdbc. Maybe is something wrong in your sql query.